# Creating a toString within a queue of two stacks

Tags: java, arrays, stack, queue

I have created a queue using two stacks from a stack class that i have created. I am wondering if it is possible to be able to read out all of the elements in the queue in order without them being lost from the stack?

The question is: Can i create a toString inside MyQueue.java that will list the order of the queue.

Here are my two files

MyQueue.java

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class MyQueue<T> {
   private MyStack<T> stack1;    // back of queue
   private MyStack<T> stack2;    // front of queue

    public MyQueue() {
         stack1 = new MyStack<T>();
         stack2 = new MyStack<T>();
    }


    private void moveStack1ToStack2()throws Exception {
        while (!stack1.isEmpty())
            stack2.push(stack1.pop());
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return stack1.isEmpty() && stack2.isEmpty();
    }

    public T peek() throws Exception {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow");
        if (stack2.isEmpty()) moveStack1ToStack2();
        T result = stack2.peek();
        return result;
    }

    // add the item to the queue
    public void enqueue(T item) throws Exception
    {
        stack1.push(item);
    }

    public T dequeue() throws Exception  {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow");
        if (stack2.isEmpty())
        {
          moveStack1ToStack2();
        }
        return (T)stack2.pop();
    }
    public int size()
    {
      return stack1.size() + stack2.size();
    }


}
```

MyStack.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class MyStack<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> al;

    public MyStack() {
        al = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void push(T item) {
        al.add(item);
    }

    public T pop() {
        if (!isEmpty())
            return al.remove(size()-1);
        else
            throw new EmptyStackException();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (al.size() == 0);
    }

    public T peek()
  {
        if (!isEmpty())
            return al.get(size()-1);
        else
            throw new EmptyStackException();
    }

    public int size() {
        return al.size();
    }

    public String toString()
  {
        return al.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by adding

```
public String toString()
{
  return stack2.toString();
}
```

to the MyQueue.java